# Automate the boring stuff (can't get BeautifulSoup to parse HTML)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This script takes a keyword(s), searches it on Google and then opens up tabs of the results in the browser. The script returns an empty array at the `select` method and I'm confused as to why. I checked the HTML of the search results and the CSS selector seems like it should work.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import webbrowser, sys, requests, bs4, pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    address = pyperclip.paste()

res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + address)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Comment: this has come up multiple times and has multiple answers on StackOverflow e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=soup.select%28%27.r+a%27%29+boring

Comment: I agree with @QHarr, this seems like a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `User-Agent` in your headers:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=python"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
assert response.status_code == 200

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for element in soup.select(".r a"):
    print(element)
```